# how to calclate time values via 2 select dropdowns in javascript and display results

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a booking form that has booking options for hours and am/pm values and then displays the amount of time chosen by the user for a booking duration

something like 2 selects for the hours
and another 2 selects for the am and pm values

so if a user selects a booking form 10 am, to 3.30pm it whould display

booking duration is for 5.30 hours

I have the code below , it does not work correctly when am and pm values are selected , and I think there must be a much better way to write the javascript than the way I have coded it, any help with this would be good, thanks

the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                //We use this this array when the user selects a booking time from the form
                var booking_ampm = new Array();
                booking_ampm["am"] = 0;
                booking_ampm["pm"] = 12;    

                //We use this this array when the user selects a booking time from the form
                var booking_prices = new Array();
                booking_prices["1"] = 1;
                booking_prices["130"] = 1.5;
                booking_prices["2"] = 2;
                booking_prices["230"] = 2.5;
                booking_prices["3"] = 3;
                booking_prices["330"] = 3.5;
                booking_prices["4"] = 4;
                booking_prices["430"] = 4.5;
                booking_prices["5"] = 5;
                booking_prices["530"] = 5.5;
                booking_prices["6"] = 6;
                booking_prices["630"] = 6.5;
                booking_prices["7"] = 7;
                booking_prices["730"] = 7.5;
                booking_prices["8"] = 8;
                booking_prices["830"] = 8.5;
                booking_prices["9"] = 9;
                booking_prices["930"] = 9.5;
                booking_prices["10"] = 10;
                booking_prices["1030"] = 10.5;
                booking_prices["11"] = 11;
                booking_prices["1130"] = 11.5;
                booking_prices["12"] = 12;
                booking_prices["1230"] = 12.5;

                //This function finds the booking start time based on the drop down selection
                function getStartTime()
                {
                    var bookingStartTime = 0;
                    //Get a reference to the form id="bookingform"
                    var theForm = document.forms["bookingform"];
                    //Get a reference to the select id="time_from"
                    var selectedTime = theForm.elements["time_from"];
                    var selectedAmPm = theForm.elements["time_from_am_pm"];

                    bookingStartTime = booking_prices[selectedTime.value];
                    bookingTimeAmPm = booking_ampm[selectedAmPm.value];

                    bookingStartTime = bookingStartTime + bookingTimeAmPm;                        

                    //finally we return bookingStartTime
                    return bookingStartTime;
                }

                //This function finds the booking end time based on the drop down selection
                function getEndTime()
                {
                    var bookingEndTime = 0;
                    //Get a reference to the form id="bookingform"
                    var theForm = document.forms["bookingform"];
                    //Get a reference to the select id="time_to"
                    var selectedTime = theForm.elements["time_to"];
                    var selectedAmPm = theForm.elements["time_to_am_pm"];

                    bookingEndTime = booking_prices[selectedTime.value];
                    bookingTimeAmPm = booking_ampm[selectedAmPm.value];

                    bookingEndTime = bookingEndTime + bookingTimeAmPm; 

                    //finally we return bookingEndTime
                    return bookingEndTime;
                }
                function calculateTotal()
                {
                    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
                    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
                    //var bookingPrice = getStartTime() + getEndTime();
                    var bookingPrice = getEndTime() - getStartTime();


                    //display the result
                    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
                    divobj.style.display = 'block';
                    divobj.innerHTML = "Booking is for hours = " + bookingPrice;

                }

                function hideTotal()
                {
                    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
                    divobj.style.display = 'none';
                }
            </script>
```

the html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="bookingform">
                <fieldset class="content-group">
                    <legend class="text-bold">Booking Request</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">User:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-control-static">This is the username</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Booking Type:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <select name="booking_type" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">Select booking type</option>
                                <option value="online">Online Booking</option>
                                <option value="local">Local Booking</option>
                                <option value="other">Other Booking Request</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control">     
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">From:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select id="time_from" name="time_from" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="130">1:30</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="230">2:30</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="330">3:30</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                <option value="430">4:30</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                                <option value="530">5:30</option>
                                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                                <option value="630">6:30</option>
                                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                                <option value="730">7:30</option>
                                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                                <option value="830">8:30</option>
                                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                                <option value="930">9:30</option>
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="1030">10:30</option>
                                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                                <option value="1130">11:30</option>
                                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                                <option value="1230">12:30</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select id="time_from_am_pm" name="time_from_am_pm" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                                                <option value="pm">pm</option>
                                                <option value="am">am</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pl-20 text-semibold">To:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select id="time_to" name="time_to" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="130">1:30</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="230">2:30</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="330">3:30</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                <option value="430">4:30</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                                <option value="530">5:30</option>
                                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                                <option value="630">6:30</option>
                                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                                <option value="730">7:30</option>
                                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                                <option value="830">8:30</option>
                                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                                <option value="930">9:30</option>
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="1030">10:30</option>
                                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                                <option value="1130">11:30</option>
                                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                                <option value="1230">12:30</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select id="time_to_am_pm" name="time_to_am_pm" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                                                <option value="pm">pm</option>
                                                <option value="am">am</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Duration:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="duration" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>

                <div id="totalPrice"></div>

                <fieldset class="content-group">
                    <legend class="text-bold">Booking Comments</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Comments:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Booking<i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix that via a simple change to the option's value.

```
<select id="time_from_am_pm" name="time_from_am_pm" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="12">pm</option>
    <option value="0">am</option>
</select>

<select id="time_to_am_pm" name="time_to_am_pm" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="12">pm</option>
    <option value="0">am</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this little script can do for you and to calculate in real time the values entered using the **onchange** event!

```js
var Booking = function() {
    this.Calculate = function(hours, minutes, isPM) { // function to calculate the time. (Returns: The date object!.)
      if (typeof isPM === "undefined") isPM = false; // if ISPM is not defined, then sets default values
      if (isPM) hours = hours + 12; // if isPM is true, then add 12 hours
      var d = new Date(); // I create a new watch!
      d.setTime(0); // Reset the clock
      d.setMinutes(minutes); // set minutes!
      d.setHours(hours); // set hours!
      return d;
    }
    
    this.Offset = function(Day, Month, Year) {
      var d = new Date(); // I create a new watch!
      d.setTime(0); // Reset the clock
      d.setDate(Day); // set day
      d.setMonth(Month); // set month
      d.setFullYear(Year); // set Year
      return d;
    }
    
    this.dateDefault = function() {
      var d = new Date(); // I create a new watch!
      d.setTime(0); // Reset the clock
      return d;
    }
    
    this.Result = function(Start, End, Offset) {
      if (typeof Start === "undefined" || Start == false) Start = this.dateDefault(); // if the variable is undefined or false, loads default values
      if (typeof End === "undefined" || End == false) End = this.dateDefault();
      if (typeof Offset === "undefined" || Offset == false) Offset = this.dateDefault();
      var d = new Date(); // I create a new watch!
      d.setTime((End.getTime() - Start.getTime()) + Offset.getTime()); // calculates the time with milliseconds and sets the clock
      return d;
    }
  }

  // A small example of how to use the function =)
var test = new Booking();
var start = test.Calculate(1, 15, false); // calculate start time
var end = test.Calculate(5, 15, true); // calculate end time
var offset = test.Offset(28, 12, 2016); // calculate the offset
var result = test.Result(start, end, offset); // calculate the result

// GET YOUR DATA! 
var minutes = result.getMinutes();
var hours = result.getHours();
var day = result.getDate();
// .. and much more! Look at the documentation of the link to find out more!
```

A small example of how to use the function =)

```js
var test = new Booking();
var start = test.Calculate(1, 15, false); // calculate start time
var end = test.Calculate(5, 15, true); // calculate end time
var offset = test.Offset(28, 12, 2016); // calculate the offset
var result = test.Result(start, end, offset); // calculate the result

// GET YOUR DATA! 
var minutes = result.getMinutes();
var hours = result.getHours();
var day = result.getDate();
// .. and much more! Look at the documentation of the link to find out more!
```

**DOCUMENTATION:** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp